# Using Laravel "Warning:require(C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such

Tags: laravel, wamp, composer-php

I am new to laravel, composer, and windows terminal. I am trying to setup laravel on my local host. I currently have wamp installed and I have used it before to create basic websites. However, I am now doing a bigger project that needs a framework so I decided to learn Laravel. I installed composer as indicated in the directions, but when i run the command

> "C:\wamp\www>composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel"

i generate an error message that says

> "[InvalidArgumentException] Project directory laravel/ is not empty."

When I open a browser and navigate to "`localhost/laravel/public`" I encounter the error message from the title of this thread:

> "Warning:require(C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such

I have also added the appropriate environment variables from the composer instructions.

I am really lost at this point, and I have spent the past 4 hours trying to debug this.

I am running Windows 8 x64.

Edit:

I tried running composer install in C:\wamp\www and received an error message

> Composer could not find the config file:
>   C:\ProgramData]ComposerSetup\bin Ti initialize a project, please
>   create a composer.json file as described in the
>   http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies for your project are not installed. Just download composer from [GetComposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/) and install it on your Windows Machine. Then navigate to your project root, you will see a composer.json file there. That file specifies all the dependencies of the project. Run composer update in that directory. Composer will then update or install all required dependencies and your application won't show the error then.

```
cd \wamp\www\yourproject
composer update
```

Comment: I tried that and when I run "composer update," I get the same error of "please create a composer.json file..."

Comment: Do you see a composer.json file in the root directory?

Comment: yes. when I open it, it looks like this:
"{
 "name": "laravel/laravel",
 "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
 "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
 "license": "MIT",
 "require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
 },
 "autoload": {
  "classmap": [

Comment: "app/commands",
   "app/controllers",
   "app/models",
   "app/database/migrations",
   "app/database/seeds",
   "app/tests/TestCase.php"
  ]
 },
 "scripts": {
  "post-install-cmd": [
   "php artisan clear-compiled",
   "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
   "php artisan clear-compiled",
   "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-create-project-cmd": [
   "php artisan key:generate"
  ]
 },
 "config": {
  "preferred-install": "dist"
 },
 "minimum-stability": "stable"
}

Comment: If you have the composer.json file, it doesn't make sense that composer cannot find it. Are you sure that you are issuing the command in the root of the project and not in the public folder? If the problem still persists, I would recommend installing a fresh copy of laravel by issuing this: composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

Answer (score 1):

> "C:\wamp\www>composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel"
>
> "[InvalidArgumentException] Project directory laravel/ is not empty."

This means `C:\wamp\www\laravel` already existed when you attempted to run the command. Remove the folder, or change the `create-project` command to use a different folder name for your new project.

> "Warning:require(C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such

You need to do a `composer install` from `C:\wamp\www\laravel`.

Comment: ok, I just now ran "composer install" from C:\wamp\www\laravel and it returned an error message: "Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin to Intiialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I was missing a folder called "vendor" and a file inside bootstrap called "compiled.php" Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you for trying!

Comment: I am facing same issue, I am missing `vendor` directory and `compiled.php` file - can you describe, how did you resolved it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the following command to get vendor folder in your project

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but i just ran this command

composer install

to install all the dependencies